# How to append multiple AWS SQS policies using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sqs, terraform-provider-aws

I do have the default policy for the SQS like below. Referred the documentation - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sqs_queue_policy

And if there is sns-subscription required, I would like to append the policy on top of the default policy.

Default policy is like below

```
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "sqs:SendMessage*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "${aws_sqs_queue.queue.arn}"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Additional policy like below

```
{
      "Sid": "topic-subscription-arn-test",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:SendMessage",
      "Resource": ["${aws_sqs_queue.queue.arn}"],
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn-test"
        }
      }
    }
```

I just tried, but the policy getting override. Any thoughts how policy can be appended using Terraform? Thanks in advance.
Looking for somekind of thought for this approach? It may be more than 2 policies, so I am trying to append these policies.

Comment: You can create an IAM policy independent of the `aws_sqs_queue_policy` and assign that to the SQS queue. In other words, you do not have to use the resource to create a policy with all that you need.

Comment: Thanks @MarkoE - This is what I tried. I created the policy with separate resource block. But instead of appending with existing policy, new policy is override the existing one. Any thoughts how to overcome?

Comment: Add the example policy you want to add and I can give an answer.

Comment: Hi @MarkoE, Thanks for the response. I edited/updated the original Question. Based on the demand, I would like to append additional policies on top of default policy.. Pls help when you get time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would strongly suggest using the `aws_iam_policy_document` data source [1] for building policies in Terraform instead of JSON. Since the SQS queue has an argument `policy` [2], the resource `aws_sqs_queue_policy` does not have to be used, but it can also be combined with the data source mentioned above. So there are two options:

1. Create a policy using data source and attach it by using the `policy` argument
2. Create a policy using data source and attach it to the `aws_sqs_queue_policy`

If you decide for the first option, here is how the code should look like:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sqs_policy" {

  statement {
    sid = "FirstSQSPolicy"
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "sqs:SendMessage*"
    ]
    resources = [
      aws_sqs_queue.queue.arn
    ]
  }

  statement {
    sid     = "topic-subscription-arn-test"
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "sqs:SendMessage"
    ]
    resources = [
      aws_sqs_queue.queue.arn
    ]
    condition {
      test     = "ArnLike"
      variable = "aws:SourceArn"
      values = [
        "arn-test"
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "terraform_queue" {
  ...
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.sqs_policy.json
}
```

For the second option, you can use the same data source and attach the JSON to the `aws_sqs_queue_policy` resource:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sqs_policy" {

  statement {
    sid = "FirstSQSPolicy"
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "sqs:SendMessage*"
    ]
    resources = [
      aws_sqs_queue.queue.arn
    ]
  }

  statement {
    sid     = "topic-subscription-arn-test"
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "sqs:SendMessage"
    ]
    resources = [
      aws_sqs_queue.queue.arn
    ]
    condition {
      test     = "ArnLike"
      variable = "aws:SourceArn"
      values = [
        "arn-test"
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue_policy" "sqs_queue_policy" {
  queue_url = aws_sqs_queue.queue.id

  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.sqs_policy.json
}
```

Using the data source for IAM policies you can add statements as you need them.

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document

[2] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sqs_queue#policy

Comment: Hi @MarkoE - Thanks for the detailed input . I need ur additional suggestion. My requirement is I need to split as 2 policy. One is default policy (It never changes). 2nd one is optional, if there is a requirement I need to add it or need to skip it. And there is a possibility there will be more than 1 rule required. 
I opened another question regarding the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73113066/count-and-for-each-combination-for-list-values-in-terraform. Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: The first suggestion fails for me with "Reference to undeclared resource - aws_sqs_queue.queue.arn". I assume you meant "aws_sqs_queue.terraform_queue.arn". This doesn't quite work for me, because I want to assign the same policy to multiple queues, created by single resource using for_each. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Alex well, the question said the name of the resource was `aws_sqs_queue.queue.arn` hence the answer is using that. That should be a simple fix, but please ask a question and I can answer it.

Comment: I solved it myself, just took some time to get the syntax correct. I tried using your first approach, which lead to circular reference but then I got it working with your second approach. I’ve marked the is answer as useful, thanks for your input :)

Comment: Glad you managed to solve it and thank you. :)